# MySQL Query with a Conditional Max Value

Tags: mysql, conditional-statements

This might be obscure but I want to set a max value on an integer in one of my queries. Basically if the value rawsentiment is greater than 500, I just want to have it be 500 but if its less, than I want it to use that value. Would this be possible? It looks like this:

```
SELECT avg( rawsentiment * magic_coefficient ) FROM sentiment
```

But I need to do something like this (warning it looks very non-SQL like)

```
SELECT avg(  ( 500 if (rawsentiment>500) else (rawsentiment) ) * magic_coefficient) FROM sentiment
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will want to check out [MySQL Least](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_least)

something like (untested):

```
SELECT AVG (least(500, rawsentiment) * magic_coefficient) FROM sentiment
```

Comment: Just add in that it would be used like: `LEAST(500, rawsentiment)`. EDIT: Or like Haim's edit.

Answer (score 2):

you can try like :

```
SELECT avg(IF(rawsentiment>500,500,rawsentiment) * magic_coefficient)
FROM sentiment
```

using [IF](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html)